# When relaxing the strong field interaction, the (t2g)^2 configuration splits into 4 states. What is the symbolic configuration of the Eg state?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration, group-theory, ligand-field-theory

[image]

When relaxing the infinitely strong field, the electrons start to feel one another's presence. They will, therefore, give rise to sets of states such as T1g, T2g... for the (t2g)^2 initial configuration. Given that Eg is a doubly degenerated state, which symbolic configurations (arrangements of electrons in dxy, dxz, dyz--> t2g) would fit this state?